# Intellij 2016.3.2 keeps changing String import to com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String

Tags: java, intellij-idea

For some unknown reason, in every class where I have methods that return String type or accept String as a parameter, intellij is automatically importing:

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String;
```

Instead of

```
java.lang.String
```

Is this a known Bug or is there a way to disable this?

Comment: Intellij usually imports stuff based on the _context_ of your code (even in copy-paste operations), so double-check, maybe you're indeed using and returning `com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String` objects. Otherwise it should be as @ElliottFrisch pointed out below

Comment: Is your project SDK setup correctly? It might not be seeing the java libraries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can exclude classes from import and completion under `File | Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import`. Check if `java.lang.String` is not added there by accident. And you can add `com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String` there to prevent it from being added to imports automatically.

Comment: This are my settings:
[Settings](https://postimg.org/image/t21d14sk3/).
Everything seems to be in order.

Comment: @DiegoOcampo Where it says no exclude patterns in the screenshot you want to add `com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String`. This will prevent IntelliJ from adding the import statement.