# Cannot resolve method 'split' in 'String'

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file and split all the words into separate Strings.

This is my code:

```
 public String[] words(String fileName) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String word;
    String[] words;
    ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
    while ((word = reader.readLine()) != null){
        words = word.split("\\s");
        for (String string : words)
            wordList.add(string);
    }

    return (String[]) wordList.toArray();
}
```

For some reason the line:
`words = word.split("\\s");`
is causing an error "Cannot resolve method 'split' in 'String'" but I have no idea why.

Comment: You'll likely need to provide more details, since it's a string function. Do you have anything else called `String` in your code?

Comment: No, I don't have.

Comment: Then it's (more or less) impossible to have this error unless something is very wrong with your Java install. Please include the complete code and Java installation details.

Comment: your code compiles and runs ok. it's impossible to have that error

Comment: What IDE do you use? Have you checked your JDK setting?

Comment: okay sorry for some reason I had the following import:
import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String;
I didn't notice it and I have no idea how it got there - but after deleting it everything works now

Comment: It appears my IDE imported the wrong String class for some reason. Figured out how to resolve it from these two questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43273812/string-cannot-be-applied-to-com-org-apache-xpath-internal-operations-string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379178/intellij-2016-3-2-keeps-changing-string-import-to-com-sun-org-apache-xpath-inter

Answer (score 1):

You can write the same in a cleaner way

Imports used

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
```

```java
public String[] words(String fileName) throws Exception { 
    ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
    String word;
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        while ((word = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Collections.addAll(wordList, word.split("\\s"));
        }
    }
    return wordList.toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Comment: It'll become even more clean if you use the try-with-resources on the `BufferedReader`.

Comment: thanks. I updated it :)